# Radius of Convergence of Laurent Series Confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Determine the largest number $R$ such that the Laurent series of

$$f(z)= \dfrac{2sin(z)}{z^2-4} + \dfrac{cos(z)}{z-3i}$$

about $z=-2$ converges for $0<|z+2|<R$?

I know the maclaurin series for sine and cosine which are valid for all complex numbers.

For $\frac{1}{z^2-4} = -\frac{0.25}{z+2} + \frac{0.25}{z-2} = \frac{-0.25}{z+2} + \frac{0.25}{-4+(z+2)} = \frac{-0.25}{z+2} + \frac{-1}{4}\frac{0.25}{1-(\frac{z+2}{4})}$, which is only valid for |$\frac{z+2}{4}$| < 1 which means $R=4$ as of now when applying the geometric series.

For $\frac{1}{z-3i} = \frac{1}{z+2-(2+3i)} = \frac{-1}{2+3i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z+2}{2+3i}}$. When applying the geometric series only valid on $|\frac{z+2}{2+3i}| < 1$ so $R = \sqrt{13}$. Is this right?

Comment: The answer looks right to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other poles are at $2,3i.$   So compute the distances from $-2.$

We get $4,\sqrt {13},$ the smaller one being $\sqrt {13}.$

Since the poles of a meromorphic function are isolated,  we get $\sqrt {13}.$  Or an annulus $0\lt\mid z+2\mid \lt\sqrt {13}.$